# USB-drive detection (Linux)

Tags: python, linux, usb, usb-drive

In my Python program I need to constantly check if a new USB drive is connected to my device, running x86 Linux (Ubuntu).
Other USB devices should not be mistaken for a USB-drive, such as keyboards, mouses, or anything else.
What is the best way to do this?

In my particular case I have a custom media player device powered by a x86 single board PC running Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Most linux systems already have some mechanism which detects new usb devices and automatically mounts them if they are storage devices, and so on. What you can do is use python's interface to the **inotify** library to monitor /mnt or /dev.

To see how it works, install `inotify-tools` or some similar named package and you can do:

```
$ inotifywait -m -e create /tmp &
```

This command monitors (-m) /tmp for the creation (-e create) of new files or directories.
Eg `touch /tmp/x` and it will output

```
/tmp/ CREATE x
```

---

You can do the same from python and its `python-inotify` or similar package.
There is the `pyinotify` command, but more usefully you can code the equivalent python program:

```
import pyinotify
wm = pyinotify.WatchManager()
notifier = pyinotify.Notifier(wm)
wm.add_watch('/tmp', pyinotify.IN_CREATE)
notifier.loop()
```

When you rm and recreate /tmp/x this prints:

```
<Event dir=False mask=0x100 maskname=IN_CREATE name=x path=/tmp pathname=/tmp/x wd=1 >
```

See the [wiki](https://github.com/seb-m/pyinotify/wiki) for a tutorial etc.

---

In your case you can monitor `/mnt` to detect newly mounted filesystems, or `/dev` to
discover new devices like `/dev/sdb` and `/dev/sdb1`. Inotify is not recursive, so only changes directly in the watched directory are returned.